# Setting the Render Background Colour?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Hi I was hoping someone could help I want to set the render background colour to complete black as I am creating a galaxy

Right now it is set to bright grey

[image]

Any help would be great

Comment: Change the **Background node** color to black in *shader nodes (World)* (this may help you: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44773/stars-background-in-cycles)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on the render engine you are using:

**Blender Internal**:
*Properties > World Tab > Horizon Color*

[image]

**Cycles**: *Properties > World Tab > Surface > Color*

[image]

Comment: If I click "Use Nodes" there, how do I "unuse nodes"?

Comment: Is there a 2.8 and higher way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

In Blender 2.9, go to World Properties in the bottom right panel. Under Surface, you'll find a Color option:

[image: Screenshot of Color option]